# Is there a way in Python to calculate MD5 hash of a file while moving it?

Tags: python

We are working with big binary files. Sometimes we need to get MD5 from file and then move it to another disk.

That's the way how we get MD5:

```py
def calc_md5sum(file_path: Path, block_size: int = 4096):
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    with file_path.open("rb") as f:
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), bytes()):
            md5_hash.update(byte_block)
    return md5_hash.hexdigest()
```

And then we are using `shutil.move` to move file (really move from disk to disk, not `os.rename()`). So we are reading file twice.

Is there a way to calculate MD5 while moving file to reduce the number of reads?

Comment: After or before the `md5_hash.update` you could write that 4k to the destination immediately. So you won't have to move just delete the original file. Maybe it worth a try...

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the two-argument `iter` "in the wild".  I thought it was all but extinct!  (Yeah, I realize this has nothing to do with answering your question.)